# Is this how to organise URLs to be referenced by RDF?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web

I am looking to set up a site that uses an RDF database (currently thinking AllegroGraph) and am trying to figure out how to structure both the URLs and the data itself. Is the following going about it the right way? Any guidance would be much appreciated!

**-- DEFINITIONS --**

**Reference 'global' RDF definitions:**

```
@prefix rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .
```

**Reference my site-specific definitions:**

`@prefix r: <http://www.simpsons.com/relationships/#> .`

> eg `http://www.simpsons.com/relationships/#parent` loads page describing parent definition as well as hyperlinks to subtypes of mother/father
>
> eg `http://www.simpsons.com/relationships/#son`  loads a page describing what a son is

`@prefix p: <http://www.simpsons.com/people/#> .`

> eg `http://www.simpsons.com/people/#Lisa` loads page with biography and photos of the person

`@prefix f: <http://www.simpsons.com/features/#> .`

> eg `http://www.simpsons.com/features/#hair` loads a page describing physical characteristics and subtypes

`@prefix pro: <http://www.simpsons.com/professions/#>` .

> eg `http://www.simpsons.com/professions/bar-tender`  loads a page describing the profession

**-- DATA TRIPLES --**

```
p:"#Homer" 
    foaf:name "Homer Simpson" ;
    r:husband p:"Marge Simpson" ;
    r:parent  p:"Bart Simpson" ;
    f:hair  "2 hairs";
    foaf:title pro:"Nucleur safety inspector" .

p:"#Bart" 
    foaf:name [rdf:Alt; rdf:_1 "Bart Simpson"; rdf:_2 "Boy"] ;
    r:"Son" p:"#Homer" .
```

Comment: *"trying to figure out how to structure both the URLs and the data itself. Is the following going about it the right way? Any guidance would be much appreciated!"*  As far as RDF is concerned, URIs are just opaque identifiers;  RDF has no concept of them being hierarchical, or related, or unrelated, in any way.  Any conventions you impose are for your own convenience, or the convenience of other users, or to make other parts of an API that you're developing easier.  You might want to look into  "cool URLs" and "hash vs slash" URIs, but that's all about social convention.

Comment: You seem to have an error in your `pro` prefix: the example misses the `#`

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is highly subjective, here is why...

URLs are a specific kind of identifiers (URIs) used for localization of resources on the Web. The formal definition is available in [RCF 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-1.1.3). These are not specific to RDF but quite useful as RDF is a format for resources description (as mentioned in the name): a pragmatic solution to localize the described resource.

In the first place, URLs are components of the Web before being components of RDF documents.

**Opacity**

In the comments is mentioned the question of the opacity of URLs. This is an idea first introduced by Tim Berners Lee in 1996 in the [design issues of the Web](http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/Axioms.html#opaque) as a personal point of view.

A more formal definition of that point is available in the W3C *Architecture of the WorlWideWeb Volume One* document in the [section 2.5. *URI Opacity*](http://www.w3.org/TR/webarch/#uri-opacity). As URLs are URIs (c.f. RFC 3968), this means that the content of an URL should not be used to determine any feature of the resource:

> It is tempting to guess the nature of a resource by inspection of a URI that identifies it. However, the Web is designed so that agents communicate resource information state through representations, not identifiers. In general, one cannot determine the type of a resource representation by inspecting a URI for that resource. For example, the ".html" at the end of "http://example.com/page.html" provides no guarantee that representations of the identified resource will be served with the Internet media type "text/html".

**Hierarchy**

There is one point about the organization of URLs to focus on, along with the opacity point: this is the structure of the URL.

Getting back to the definition, you will find the syntax model for the URI (and by specialization for the URL) in [section 3 of the RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3). Here are defined the components of an URI. We should pay attention to a specific component: the *path*.

Details about the organization of the *path* are available in [section 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3):

> The path component contains data, usually organized in hierarchical form, that, along with data in the non-hierarchical query component (Section 3.4), serves to identify a resource within the scope of the URI's scheme and naming authority (if any).

Hierarchy is explicitely stated here.

**Conclusion**

It is easy to conclude that URLs should have no real meaning but this is highly subjective (my personal point of view here: we should not forget that the Web is in the first place for human users). The hierarchy of resources is an important aspect to consider. Beside that, a subtle point is its relationship with opacity. Roy Fielding, in [a mail exchange](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/rest-discuss/conversations/topics/5369), suggests that opacity only applies to clients, what makes things quite simple. And this respects the terms of the *Architecture of the WorlWideWeb Volume One* document (cited text above).

Hierarchy is a specific kind of relationship, semantics accept a really rich variety of relationships. Here is what you should think about when considering your data structure.

In a few words, this is more a question of [RESTful architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) than a question of semantics. For more details on that point, you should refer to the [section on the topic in the *microformats* website](http://microformats.org/wiki/rest/opacity).